# How do I create new projects that use a remote SDK in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I set up Ruby and Rails via RVM in a Vagrant box. In RubyMine, I've successfully added that box as a deployment server, and the remote-rvm Ruby interpreter in the `Ruby SDK and Gems` window.

However, when I open the `New Project` dialog and select `New Application` (Rails), there is no SDK selected in the `Ruby SDK` and `Rails Version` dropdown menus.

The only item available in the `Ruby SDK` dropdown is `Add Ruby SDK...` This item opens a `Select Ruby Interpreter Path` file browser window, but I can browse locally only.

So, I am unable to create projects that use Rails on a remote box.

How do I populate those dropdowns with the remote SDK? What am I missing?

Versions:

- RubyMine 2016.1.2
- Ruby 2.3.1
- Rails 4.2.6
- RVM 1.11.3.9

Comment: thats the same for me. i usually create a project through terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no option for that, because remote SDKs were removed from the list of available ones due to some [technical reasons](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-12846), but we've submitted a [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-18210) to implement it back, so please vote for it.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know this isn't possible. I voted for the request.